# Can we give different machine path other than same machine on which SQL Server installed for filestream?

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I want my filestream data to be kept on different servers other than the server on which SQL Server is installed. The servers will be in the same network path.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. It's right there in the [manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh759341.aspx):

> Filestream is currently not supported on an SMB file share.

Databases *can* be stored on a file share, with recent versions; filestream data still cannot.